# Add yaml-loader in i18n tags in a Vue-CLI 3 project

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-i18n

Using Vue-i18n and following [this tutorial](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/sfc.html#basic-usage), I managed to add  tags in json in my project gererated by vue-cli.

In this page, there is an example to write yaml instead of json. But there is no example with the Vue-Cli 3 Webpack managment.

So I tried this :

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('i18n')
      .resourceQuery(/blockType=i18n/)
      .use('i18n')
        .loader('@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader')
        .loader('yaml-loader')
        .end();
  }
}
```

But I've got this error

```
error  in ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=custom&index=0&blockType=i18n

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
>       "en": {
|               "hello": "Hello !"
|       }

 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?vue&type=custom&index=0&blockType=i18n 1:0-233 1:249-252 1:254-484 1:254-484
 @ ./src/components/HelloWorld.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
```

I don't fully understand how webpack-chain is working, what do I missing ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-cli-plugin-i18n/issues/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct webpack-chain api usage for adding a yaml preloader would be

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('i18n')
      .resourceQuery(/blockType=i18n/)
      .use('i18n')
        .loader('@kazupon/vue-i18n-loader')
        .end()
      .use('yaml-loader')
        .loader('yaml-loader')
        .end();
  }
}
```

I'm also not a big fan of this syntax, but like that you should get it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using JSON syntax instead of YAML syntax and that's the reason you get this error.
e.g. JSON syntax:

```
  "en": {
          "hello": "Hello !"
  }
```

YAML syntax:

```
en:
 hello: Hello!
```